# jQuery fullcalendar: No scrollbar displayed when in monthview

Tags: jquery-ui, scrollbar, fullcalendar

If i have many events for a day then the height of month view is increased but the vertical scroll-bar is not displayed because of which i am unable to see all events, Scroll-bar is displayed correctly in Week view.

Comment: what are you talking about? outlook?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

jquery fullcalendar scrollbar in basic month view.

please modify below class in fullcalendar.css file

```
.fc-view {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 550px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```